# Clarification on Clustered index scan and Clustered Index Seek

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, execution-plan

I have created one table with 80000 records with `Cluster Index` on `CustomerID` column.  When I queried the following statements the execution plan behaves in differently.  Can anyone clarify the same.

```
select * from customer
```

> Showing Cluster Index Scan,  So this is correct.

```
select * from customer where CustomerID=80000
```

> Execution plan shows ClusterIndex Seek,  So this is correct.

```
select * from customer where CustomerID between 1 and 70000
```

> Execution plan still shows ClusterIndex Seek why?

As per the statistics the row count is 90% then the optimizer have to use 'ClusterIndex Scan' but it's using 'Cluster Index Seek' Why?  All statistics are up to date and I have checked the Estimated row and actual rows are same then why the optimizer choose 'Cluster Index Seek' For getting 90% of rows among total records.

Answer (score 10):

> Execution plan still shows ClusterIndex Seek why?

The **initial seek** down the b-tree is to find the first row where `CustomerID >= 1`.

From that point on, the storage engine remembers the current **scan** position, and returns the next row **in index order** that qualifies each time a row is requested by a parent plan operator. The **scan** comes to an end as soon as a row is encountered that does not match the predicate `CustomerID <= 70000`.

The effect is that the 'seek' is an **initial seek**, followed by a **partial ordered scan** of the index.

This is usually more efficient than scanning the whole index, even where 90% of the rows are expected to qualify. The key point to get straight in your mind is that a separate b-tree seek is not performed for each row.

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be simple here, assuming you just have one clustered index on table and your query is like

```
select * from customer where CustomerID between 1 and 70000
```

In above case seek would be preferred by optimizer because first the index would search the data based on condition `CustomerID=1` and would find the first row which matches the predicate. Then it would eventually go down the index till it reaches end of the range that is `7000` to get the relevant data. So all together query engine has to read only *relevant* pages to give you information and so that would still qualify under seek.